# tru64 boot in single mode on every boot

Tags: tru64

Of course inittab is not set to runlevel 1 as default.
Every time i boot tru64 boot dka0 boot but..in single mode.
I not see any error message

```
dsfmgr: NOTE: updating kernel basenames for system at /
    scp kevm tty00 tty01 lp0 dsk0 cdrom0 dsk1
starting LSM in boot mode

INIT: SINGLE-USER MODE
```

When i run exit on shell,it goes in runlevel 3
and boot normally.
What can it be?
I have run the os from cd and try  the command

```
verify
```

and give me no problems
But boot every time first in single user mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check Alpha SRM console configuration.
Confirm `boot_osflags` parameter is set to `a`.

1. For examine boot_osflags environment variable is set.
   `>>> show boot_osflags`
2. For changing SRM console into multi user mode.
   `>>> set boot_osflags a`

For more details, I've found the document in old archive.

https://archive.org/stream/dec-srm_cnsol_users_gde/srm_cnsol_users_gde_djvu.txt

Comment: Thanks! Useful in 2022!